# How can I write backslash in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I want to write following in MathJax:

```
L(A)\L(B)
```

When I type following:

```
$L(A)\ L(B)$
```

It prints: $L(A)\ L(B)$

When I type following:

```
$L(A)\\ L(B)$
```

It prints: $L(A)\\ L(B)$

How can I make `\` appear in MathJax?

Comment: The backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in $\LaTeX$, cf. point 15 in the post [MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  In many contexts an escape character is made *graphic* (visible) by doubling it (e.g. `\\\`), but in $\LaTeX$ this means a *newline* break.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want a real backslash, and not something spaced like a binary operation, use
`L(A)\backslash L(B)` to get
$$
L(A) \backslash L(B)
$$

Comment: You can also surround `\backslash` with `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` to change the spacing, giving something similar (the same?) as `\setminus`. So `L(A)\mathbin{\backslash} L(B)` gives $L(A)\mathbin{\backslash} L(B)$ while `L(A)\mathrel{\backslash} L(B)` gives $L(A)\mathrel{\backslash} L(B)$. (The spacing *is* different, honest!)

Answer (score 26):

Use `\setminus` for the result $()\setminus()$.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a list of possible solutions that I could come up with (includes a curated Detexify output), the first two are the other two current answers:

1. $L(A)\backslash L(B)$ `$L(A)\backslash L(B)$`
2. $L(A)\setminus L(B)$`$L(A)\setminus L(B)$` (looks the same as the next too)
3. $L(A)\mathbin{\setminus}L(B)$ `$L(A)\mathbin{\backslash}L(B)$`
4. $ L(A)⧵L(B)$ `$ L(A)⧵L(B)$`using [U+29F5](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+29F5) "Reverse Solidus Operator"
5. $L(A)\text{\ }\!L(B)$ `$L(A)\text{\ }\!L(B)$` PS `/` also works in `\text`
6. $L(A)$\ $\!L(A)$ `$L(A)$\ $\!L(A)$` (broken into two MathJax pieces) and similarly
7. $L(A)$ \ $L(A)$ `$L(A)$ \ $L(A)$`
8. $L(A) \diagdown L(B)$ `$A \diagdown B$`
9. $L(A)╲L(B)$ `$L(A)╲L(B)$` using [U+2572](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2572) "Box Drawings Light Diagonal Upper Left to Lower Right"
10. $L(A) \smallsetminus L(B)$ `$A \smallsetminus B$`
11. $L(A)﹨L(B)$ `$L(A)﹨L(B)$` using [U+FE68](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FE68) "Small Reverse Solidus"
12. $L(A)＼L(B)$ `$L(A)＼L(B)$` using [U+FF3C](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF3C) "Fullwidth Reverse Solidus"
13. $L(A)\backprime L(B)$ `$L(A)\backprime L(B)$`
14. $L(A)\searrow  L(B)$ `$L(A)\searrow L(B)$`

Comment: 6 and 7 are "wrong", in the sense that you shouldn't exit mathmode like that...!

Comment: Point 4 can also be made less obscure using `\unicode{x29f5}`: $L(A)\unicode{x29f5}L(B)$. Same for points 9, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 14):

For fun:

> How can I make \ appear in MathJax?

The command `\cancel` produces a forward slash: $\require{cancel}\cancel{\phantom{k}}$. A simple rotation flips it around to produce a backslash. So

```
\require{cancel}

L(A)\!\!\! 

\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\cancel{\phantom{mm}}}

\!\!\! L(B)
```

gives

$$\require{cancel}L(A)\!\!\! \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\cancel{\phantom{mm}}}\!\!\! L(B).$$

<sub>This is *clearly*  <s>easier</s>  better than `\setminus` or `\backslash` :P</sub>

Comment: or rotate / through 90

Comment: (+1) Aah yes, a simple answer from TheSimpliFire